# How do I import this interface from the React-Particles-JS library?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, typescript, particles.js

I'm trying to separate my params from my JSX in the react-particles-js library. 
I place my params in an Object:

```
let options = {
        "particles": {
            "number": {
                "value": 50
            },
            "size": {
                "value": 3
            }
        },
        "interactivity": {
            "events": {
                "onhover": {
                    "enable": true,
                    "mode": "repulse"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I write my JSX:

```
<Particles params={options}/>
```

When I do so I get the error

```
The types of 'interactivity.events.onhover.mode' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"repulse" | "grab" | "push" | "remove" | "bubble" | InteractivityMode[] | undefined'.  TS2322
```

I can't import the InteractivityMode interface since it's not exported in the library. I'm not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the type definition of it

https://github.com/Wufe/react-particles-js/blob/master/index.d.ts

```
export type IParticlesParams = RecursivePartial<{
  ...
}>

export interface ParticlesProps {
    width?: string;
    height?: string;
    params?: IParticlesParams;
    style?: any;
    className?: string;
    canvasClassName?: string;
}

type Particles = ComponentClass<ParticlesProps>;
```

So import the type **IParticlesParams** and use it

```
import { Particles, IParticlesParams } from "react-particles-js";

let options: IParticlesParams = {
  ...
}
```

And if there are any further type error, handle it inside your file as normal would be fine